# Use Asynchronous Iteration to do polling in my backend

Tags: javascript, promise, eventemitter

Is it a good practice to usage an Asynchronous Iteration to show the status of some resource in my backend? For example:

```
const item = driver.get(idOfDriver)

try {
  for await (const { status } of item) {
    console.log(status)
  }
} catch (err) {
  // do something here
} finally {
  // the driver arrived in the final location
  const { finalLocation, id } = item
  console.log(`final location of driver ${id} is ${finalLocation`)
}
```

I'm doing something that Asynchronous Iteration were not meant for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `item` is an infinite iterator that emits status updates? Then what's the `finally` good for?

Comment: @Bergi Not infinite... when the driver arrives in the location, new properties will exist (finalLocation is one example). The iterator would exist to emit status until the status != 'COMPLETE'

Comment: Unless you need to emit those incomplete statuses, I don't see what the iterator would be good for. Just use a simple promise for the new properties

Comment: @Bergi I need to show the current status in the interface

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I get you wrong, but I guess you just try to initiate data fetching in `get` and wait until it's loaded, then do some processing. In such scenario you don't need async iteration which is used in more complex scenarios when dealing with series of promises.

You can do it using ES6 promises:

```
driver.get(idOfDriver)
  .then(({ finalLocation, id }) => {
    console.log(`final location of driver ${id} is ${finalLocation`)
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Or using ES7 `async/await` syntax:

```
try {
  const {finalLocation, id} = await driver.get(idOfDriver);
  console.log(`final location of driver ${id} is ${finalLocation`)
}
catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```